# Cordova Control-media-plugin and bluetooth speaker

Tags: cordova, bluetooth, cordova-plugins, android-mediaplayer, speaker

I am using cordova-plugin-music-controls 2 and have created a media panel that works correctly. But The app can't handle button presses on the Bluetooth speaker, but handles it in notifications. How do I control multimedia using a Bluetooth speaker?

```
var data = {
track: 'Test',
artist: 'Test',
isPlaying: false,
playIcon: 'media_play',
pauseIcon: 'media_pause',
prevIcon: 'media_prev',
nextIcon: 'media_next',
closeIcon: 'media_close',
notificationIcon: 'notification'
};
var nxt = 1;
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
console.log("device ready");
mediaNotification();
}
function play() {
data = {
    track: 'Test',
    artist: nxt,
    isPlaying: false,
    playIcon: 'media_play',
    pauseIcon: 'media_pause',
    prevIcon: 'media_prev',
    nextIcon: 'media_next',
    closeIcon: 'media_close',
    notificationIcon: 'notification'
}
MusicControls.create(data
);
nxt = nxt + 1;
}
function mediaNotification() {
    function musicControlsEvent(action) {
        const message = JSON.parse(action).message;
        switch (message) {
        case 'music-controls-next':
            play();
            break;
        case 'music-controls-previous':
            break;
        case 'music-controls-next':
            play();
            console.log("play");
            break;
        case 'music-controls-pause':
            break;
        case 'music-controls-play':
            play();
            break;
        case 'music-controls-destroy':
            break;
        case 'music-controls-toggle-play-pause':
            play();
            break;
        case 'music-controls-seek-to':
            break;
        case 'music-controls-media-button':
            play();
            break;
        case 'music-controls-media-button-stop':
            play();
            break;
        case 'music-controls-headset-unplugged':
            // Do something
            break;
        case 'music-controls-headset-plugged':
            // Do something
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
MusicControls.create(data
);
MusicControls.subscribe(musicControlsEvent);
MusicControls.listen();
}
```

I have tried using different Bluetooth devices, but there is no result.

Comment: Could you clarify on _The app can't handle button presses on the Bluetooth speaker, but handles it in notifications_? Your app does not react to button operation on your connected speaker? In case you are getting your mediaNotifications you are asking how to pause the music for example?

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan, In theory after clicking on the button in the speaker, the nxt variable should increase by one and this should be displayed in the notification in the artist

Comment: As far as I understand cordova-plugin-music-controls it does not offer anything related to bluetooth. Did you add any other library to your project?

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan, no i didn't

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan but how can i handle the speakers buttons? i want to to do something when user pushed the next button on the speaker. not only play the next song, but, for example, change the page or show a message

Comment: Just for my understanding, what happens now if you press the button on the speaker? Does it change the song to the next?

Comment: @MichaelKotzjaninafter pressing the button on the speaker, the value of nt var should be increased by one, but this does not happen

Comment: But does it change the song or does it do nothing?